# my suggestion about getter syntax in angular to handle app name duplication

Tags: angularjs

I know it is a bad practice to use this syntax to register controllers in angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('mainController',function(){
    // code
});
```

because of global variables issue so it's recommended to use the getter syntax in angular:

```
angular.module('app',[]);
angular.module('app').controller('mainController',function(){
    //code
};
```

but every time I have to write the name of my application to get it so I think in another solution to do that:

```
'use strict';
const _APP_ = (function(){
    var appName = 'app';
    var result = {
        init: function(dependencies){
            document.body.setAttribute('ng-app',appName);
            if(!dependencies || !Array.isArray(dependencies)){
                dependencies = [];
            }
            angular.module(appName,dependencies);
        },
        $: function(){
            return angular.module(appName);
        }
    };
    return Object.freeze(result);
})();
```

now app.js file just has:

```
'use strict';
(function(){
    _APP_.init();
})();
```

and to create a new controller:

```
'use strict';
(function(){
    _APP_.$().controller('mainController',ctrl);
    function ctrl(){
        // code
    }
})();
```

I'm always interested in the best practices so I need your feedback about my solution or if there is a better.

Comment: What kind of `global var issue` you talking about? Global vars is a main behavior of JavaScript.

Comment: see that [https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y010] @lin

Comment: Well made `angular` or `angular.module` is nothing else than a global var / method of global var too. I don't know why to things that complicated. Where on the link you posted is an issue with global vars explaned?

Comment: what do you mean? @lin

Comment: if global variables are not bad or need to be used carefully, why we use IFEE syntax?? 


    Wrap Angular components in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

Why?: An IIFE removes variables from the global scope. This helps prevent variables and function declarations from living longer than expected in the global scope, which also helps avoid **variable collisions**.
this is from John Papa style guide of angular @lin

Comment: I think you getting things wrong. Your solution e.g. `const _APP_ = (function(){...` is not IFEE while `const _APP_` is defined as a global const. IFEE is made for prepend collisions on components and not the application itself. The example in the link you posted is not that good (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#javascript-scopes). I think it should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/syLLe37a/

Comment: I know my const is global but it is secured from any changes and collisions and I do that to stop writing the app name every time. Do you understand my point of view??? @lin

Comment: I think its an overhead. There is no need for an application instance invoker at all. IMO there is no difference of using `var app = ...` or `const _APP_ = ....` Both solutions are not IIFE and both solutions does not prepend from writing the `app name every time`. So, IMO there is no need for an application invoker. You should be fine by writing `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);` and using myApp as global application instance. I could repeat it, IFEE is made to prepend from component collisions and not the application instance itself.